# Same type for receiver and argument in Kotlin function

Tags: kotlin, generics

Is there any difference between these two Kotlin extension functions?

```
fun Any?.f(o: Any?) = 100

fun <T> T.g(o: T) = 100
```

Is it possible to rewrite `g` in such a way that the type of its argument and receiver are forced to be the same?

That is, `10.g(5)` and `"x".g("y")` are OK, but `10.g("y")` does not compile.

Edit:
Given [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26538980/459391), I guess the answer to my second question is no, uless one adds additional arguments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this is not possible officially at the time of writing this answer (Kotlin 1.7.20).

However, internally Kotlin compiler supports such case, it allows to change the default behavior and use exact type parameters. This is controlled by the internal `@Exact` annotation and it is used in many places across the Kotlin stdlib.

With some hacking we can enable this behavior in our own code:

```kotlin
@Suppress("INVISIBLE_REFERENCE", "INVISIBLE_MEMBER")
fun <T> @kotlin.internal.Exact T.g(o: @kotlin.internal.Exact T) = 100
```

Of course, this is purely a hack and it may stop working in future versions of Kotlin.

**Update**

Answering your first question on whether there is a difference between using `Any` and `T`. Generic functions make the most sense if the type parameter is not only consumed, but also passed somewhere further. For example, if the function returns `T` or it receives an object that consumes `T`:

```kotlin
fun main() {
    var result = 5.g(7)
}

fun <T> T.g(o: T): T = if (...) this else o
```

In this case `result` is of type `Int`. If we use `Any` instead of `T`, `result` would have to be `Any` as well.

Comment: I'm so happy I asked. Thanks a lot for your informative answer!